# Sending a variable in a C# EventHandler?

Tags: c#

How can I send a variable with a newly created EventHandler? 
The code I have is something like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{   
    Button buttonX = new Button();
    buttonX.Location = new Point(0, 0 + offset);
    buttonX.Size = new Size(310, 48);
    buttonX.Click += new EventHandler(buttonClick);
}

private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show();
}
```

How can I can make it like

```
buttonX.Click += new EventHandler(buttonClick , i);

private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e, int i)
{
    MessageBox.Show(i.toString());
}
```

Comment: If you want it to work with a standard button, you can't do that.  However, if you can explain the end result that you need, there is probably another way to do it.  So, what is it that you are trying to do -- what is "i" for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would create a class derived from EventArgs that carries the additional data points that you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.eventargs.aspx

So instead of just using EventArgs you would create an EventArgs for the event you are raing.

```
public class ButtonClickedEventArgs : EventArgs
{
    public int EventInteger { get; private set; }

    public ButtonClickedEventArgs(int i)
    {
        EventInteger = i;
    }
}
```

And then when you raise the event you would create the ButtonClickedEventArgs class and pass that with the EventHandler.

Answer (score 8):

Closures are grand.  You can use lambda notation:

```
buttonX.Click += (sender, e) => buttonClick(sender, e, i);
```

or anonymous delegate notation:

```
buttonX.Click += delegate (object sender, EventArgs e) { buttonClick(sender, e, i); };
```

However, [you're going to have trouble if you capture the loop variable](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful.aspx).

Instead, do

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{   
    Button buttonX = new Button();
    buttonX.Location = new Point(0, 0 + offset);
    buttonX.Size = new Size(310, 48);
    var i_copy = i;
    buttonX.Click += (sender, e) => buttonClick(sender, e, i_copy);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your scenario, just utilize the `Tag` property; don't mix the solution with the `Click` event; you don't need to "pass" `i` every time to the event; just tag it to the control since it's always the same; that way you don't have to worry about closure.

Change your code to this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{   
    Button buttonX = new Button();
    buttonX.Location = new Point(0, 0 + offset);
    buttonX.Size = new Size(310, 48);
    buttonX.Click += new EventHandler(buttonClick);
    buttonX.Tag = i;
}

private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(((Button)sender).Tag.ToString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do that, but what you can do is use an intermediate lambda:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    int j = i; // Need to do this to fix closure issue

    Button buttonX = new Button();
    buttonX.Location = new Point(0, 0 + offset);
    buttonX.Size = new Size(310, 48);
    buttonX.Click += (sender, e) => {
        buttonClick(sender, e, j);
    };
}


private void buttonClick(object sender, EventArgs e, int i)
{
    MessageBox.Show(i.toString());
}
```

Comment: When you make a copy of the loop variable, actually use the copy :)

Comment: For your closure issue, shouldn't you pass `j` to your handler instead of `i`?